# Why does the C# compiler insert an explicit interface implementation?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I ran into a strange C# edge case and am looking for a good work-around.

There is a class that I do not control that looks like this:

```
namespace OtherCompany
{
    public class ClassIDoNotControl
    {
        public void SomeMethod(string argument)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name));
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to inherit from this class in a class I *do* control. Additionally, I'd like to specify an interface on it:

```
interface IInterfaceIDoControl
{
    void SomeMethod(string argument);
}

class ClassIDoControl : OtherCompany.ClassIDoNotControl, IInterfaceIDoControl
{
}
```

If all of these files are in the same assembly, everything works great:

```
namespace MyCompany
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IInterfaceIDoControl i = new ClassIDoControl();
            i.SomeMethod("Hello World!"); // Prints "Main"
        }
    }
 }
```

But, if I move "ClassIDoNotControl" into another assembly, I don't get what I expected. Instead, I see "MyCompany.IInterfaceIDoControl.SomeMethod" for the output implying an extra stack frame.

The reason is that under the covers, the C# compiler is changing "ClassIDoControl" to look like this:

```
class ClassIDoControl : OtherCompany.ClassIDoNotControl, IInterfaceIDoControl
{
    void IInterfaceIDoControl.SomeMethod(string argument)
    {
        base.SomeMethod(argument);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this compiler-generated extra layer of indirection with explicitly implemented interfaces?

Comment: I am surprised it works in the first case.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Short answer:** The CLR requires that all methods that implement an interface method must be virtual ([Ecma 335 Partition II](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/C/1/DC1B219F-3B11-4A05-9DA3-2D0F98B20917/Partition%20II%20Metadata.doc) Section 12.1).

**Long answer:**

- If the method in the base class is already virtual, then nothing extra is needed: the interface method can be bound to it.
- If the method in the base class is *not* virtual, but in the same assembly, the sneaky compiler actually *makes it virtual and final*. Reflector confirms this. <sup><sub>(“final” is the CLR terminology for “sealed” in C#.)</sub></sup>
- If the method in the base class is not virtual and in another assembly, then obviously the compiler can’t do this because it can’t modify the already-compiled assembly. Therefore, the only option here is to insert a redirect method that implements the interface method. Like all methods that implement an interface method, it too is marked *virtual and final*.

So the answer to your last question, “Is there a way to avoid this?”, is unfortunately no.

Comment: Ah ha! I didn't notice that subtle change in the C# disassembly in Reflector, but you're right that it occurs in the IL view with that "virtual final" trick. I learned something new today.