# Overriding interface method return type with derived class in implementation

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism

I am trying to implement (C#) an interface method in a class, returning a derived type instead of the base type as defined in the interface:

```
interface IFactory
{
    BaseCar GetCar();
}

class MyFactory : IFactory
{
    MyCar GetCar()
    {
    }
}
```

Where, of course:

```
class MyCar : BaseCar
{

}
```

However, the following error happens:

'MyFactory' does not implement interface member 'IFactory.GetCar()'. 'MyFactory.BaseCar()' cannot implement IFactory.GetCar()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'BaseCar'.

Can anyone point me as to why this fails, and how would be the best way to work around it?

Comment: This is a duplicate: [“Interface not implemented” when Returning Derived Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121283/interface-not-implemented-when-returning-derived-type), and [polymorphism for properties specified by interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670069/polymorphism-for-properties-specified-by-interfaces)

Comment: Thanks @cody-gray, somehow missed those links previously.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use Generics

```
interface IFactory<T> where T: BaseCar
{
    T GetCar();
}

class MyFactory : IFactory<MyCar>
{
    MyCar GetCar()
    {
    }
}


class MyCar : BaseCar
{

}
```

Comment: `GetCar` in `MyFactory` should be public, and `T` is covariant, so you could mark it so with `out` on the interface if using C# 4.0.

Comment: @vcsjones: If BaseFactory implements IFactory<BaseCar> and DerivedFactory inherits BaseFactory but implements IFactory<DerivedCar>, is there any guarantee, when using covariance, that using a DerivedFactory as an IFactory<BaseCar> will use the DerivedFactory implementation of GetCar?

Answer (score 17):

There are 2 ways to accomplish this. You can either use generics or explicitly implement interface members.

Generics

```
interface IFactory<T> where T: BaseCar
{
    T GetCar();
}

class MyFactory : IFactory<MyCar>
{
    MyCar GetCar()
    {
    }
}
```

Explicitly implemented members

```
interface IFactory
{
    BaseCar GetCar();
}

class MyFactory : IFactory
{
    BaseCar IFactory.GetCar()
    {
        return GetCar();
    }

    MyCar GetCar()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The second implementation is quite confusing: the call `MyFactory.GetCar()` looks like ambiguous when made against an object of class `MyFactory`.

Answer (score 5):

Your `GetCar` method has to return a `BaseCar` in order to implement the interface. As the error says, the class' method's return type must match the interface's method's return type.

There's nothing stopping you creating an instance of `MyCar`, then returning that:

```
BaseCar GetCar()
{
    return new MyCar();
}
```

An alternative, if you want to get the typed version of the new class, is to use generics as per [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564629/593627).

Comment: In this case, there is, because GetCar() is used by many others in different scenarios, where they need to return MyCar, MyOtherCar, etc., without them having to cast it from BaseCar every time.