# c# object interface return type covariance

Tags: c#, generics, types, covariance, covariant-return-types

C# compiler:

error CS0738: `Field<T>' does not implement interface member`Field.Value.get' and the best implementing candidate `Field<T>.Value.get' return type`T' does not match interface member return type `object'

```
public interface Field
{
   object Value {get;}
}

public class MyField<T> : Field
{
   T _value;
   public T Value
   {
      get
      {
         return _value;
      }
   }
}
```

Why ? List < T > extends List in microsoft classes, but i as a user (copying same design pattern) am not allowed to do that? why?

Trying where T: object also gives a compiler error...

How do i fix this?

the other 1.000.000 threads on the same subject, Say :
blablabla, 'return type covariance', blablabla, 'you cant'.

They do not propose a solution or a workaround on how to compile this beast.
Requirements:
1) Field is an interface that cannot take generics. Evil framework called "unity" forbids generics.
2) Field < T > which "implements Field" has generic T.

Comment: side note: why are you having field `_value` as public? this defeats the purpose of encapsulating fields... make it private

Comment: The C# compiler loves you and wants you to be safe and productive, and so sometimes it stops you from doing dangerous, unproductive things. Just like your mom didn't let you ride your bicycle on the roof, even though that would have been awesome.

Comment: There is nothing special about `List<T>`. It's an ordinary class written by people with no special access to compiler internals, and the compiler does nothing special with it. If you want to know how the authors of `List<T>` managed to implement `IList`, you can read the source code.

Comment: i looked at the source code (although illegal), and found how to do it with special Omega_unknown_Microsoft_Unmentioned_Compiler_Syntax, called specific interface implementation.

Comment: reading source code is not illegal atleast for .net. you can download it from [Microsoft web site](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Comment: @user2186597 List<T> is open-source (so not illegal to look at). The technique known as explicit interface implementation (suggested in M.kazem Akhgary's answer) is exactly how List<T> implements IList (non-generic) interface. Here's link to the code on github: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs

Comment: It's called [Explicit Interface Implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) and as you can see, it's neither special or MS unmentioned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because _"[your question is just a rant in disguise: '........ sucks, am I right?'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)”_

Comment: i didn't use the keyword "sucks", so you are sadly mistaken...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding interface method return type with derived class in implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564593/overriding-interface-method-return-type-with-derived-class-in-implementation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement interface explicitly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx

The same pattern is used on non generic version of `IEnumerable` and generic `IEnumerable<T>`

You can do the same and have generic interface too.

```
public interface Field
{
    object Value { get; }
}

public interface Field<T> : Field
{
    new T Value { get; }
}

public class MyField<T> : Field<T>
{
    public T Value { get; } // generic

    object Field.Value => Value; // non generic
}
```

Now if you have `Field<T>` on your hand you can use `T` happily. if you have `Field` you get object form of value `T`

Comment: Awesome! I am removing my answer, this is far better! +1!

Comment: It would be good style to mark the `Field<T>` version of `Value` with `new` to indicate that the hiding was intentional.

Comment: Why does Field<T> interface inherit from Field ? 
Would it not be better that MyField<T> : Field<T>, Field instead? Then you do not hide the inheritance.

Comment: @Nyranith: That would arguably be better, but not because of any "hiding" of inheritance. Rather: by inheriting from `Field`, the author of `Field<T>` *requires* that all classes which implement the interface do this trick of implementing both versions of `Value`, which is burdensome and irritating.  However, note that in the base class libraries, `IEnumerator<T>` does inhert from `IEnumerator`, so this sort of thing does have some precedent.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Object Value
   {
      get
      {
         return _value;
      }
   }
```

May be you need this. Since every data type inherits Object but not vice versa. I guess this is why covariance trouble  is coming.

Comment: good news, is that it compiles !!! But it pollutes my namespace.

Trying to have both methods results in :
error CS0102: 'Field<T>' already contains a definition for `Value'

Answer (score 1):

You do not use template type in the interface, but rather object.Try this instead:

```
 interface Field<T>
    {
        T Value { get; }
    }

public class MyField<T> : Field<T>
    {
        private T _value;
        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The OP stated that one of his constraints is that the interface cannot support generics

Comment: Then Field<T> interface will have to extend Field which cause the same compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want. But if your interface can't be generic then this is what will work.

```
public interface Field
{
   object Value {get;}
}

public class MyField<T> : Field
{
   public T _value;

   public T MyTypedValue
   {
       get 
       { 
           return _value; 
       }
   }

   public object Value
   {
       get
       {
          return _value;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: you are close, i want MyTypedValue to also share the same name as Value method

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Field<T> : Field
{
   T _value;

   //specific interface implementation
   object Field.Value
   {
     get
     {
        return _value;
     }
   }

   public T Value
   {
      get
      {
         return _value;
      }
   }
}
```